# Function references as objects Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have

```
fun getRealGrade(x: Double) = x
fun getGradeWithPenalty(x: Double) = x - 1

fun getScoringFunction(isCheater: Boolean): (Double) -> Double {
    if (isCheater) {
        return ::getGradeWithPenalty
    }

    return ::getRealGrade
}
```

What is the use of `(Double) -> Double` in `getScoringfunction`?

If I dont undestand the syntax correct me  `isCheater` val is boolean here, and function returns double but  what does  this `(Double)` do?

What I get is:

```
fun sayHello() {
    println("Hello")
}
```

In this example
`sayHello` has a type of `() -> Unit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function doesn't return a `(Double)`, it returns a `(Double) -> Double`, i.e. it returns a *function*. The function that it returns takes a double and returns a double.

You would use it like this

```
fun main() {
    val scoreFunction: (Double) -> Double = getScoringFunction(true); // returns the cheater scoring function
    val score = scoreFunction(10) // score = 9, they were graded with penalty
}
```

In your second example, the return type is `Unit`. In Kotlin, a function that returns no value is said to return `Unit`, a singleton object. `() -> Unit` is a *function* that takes no parameters and returns no value.